# All application data in single redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux.
I have an app with five pages and every page have some tables.

should I save all pages data in store even those pages not rendered currently?

If answer is yes, what happen when I have large data in total?(5000 records)

If answer is no, help me to understand it and how manage deferent page States.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear cut way to this problem as is with most programming conundrum.

storing all the state information in redux is alright and manageable especially if you don't really have a lot of states or moving parts in the store. but in larger applications, you don't really want to update the redux store every time someone clicks an input field, especially if that is a trivial state it is updating(like states of a text field like focused, pristine and dirty). getting a good ratio of stuff in the redux store and the local state store can get tricky at first but you'll get the hang of it with more experience, though a general rule of thumb is

> does this state affect another component?

If you answered yes, then you might want to move that to redux. otherwise leaving it in the local state store is fine. As for your concern with dealing with large data, take note that you should not load ALL the data on page load. load only the things you need(better if you can preload these) and fetch additional data as needed.

i.e. if you have an index page that should display the top 10 most popular tv shows this season. instead of seeding your index page with all the shows in your database, just load the 10 most popular tv shows. then proceed to fetch data you need as you navigate around the app

Comment: thanks for reply.can you give me some link about this or sample of multi pages app with react redux?